# Bash script to dynamically find and construct the url and download

Tags: bash, downloads, url

I would like to write an script which opens a URL (not a complete URL link) and finds the latest available version of a file. Then, it will go one level up from that directory, find some file in that directory and repeat this process until it has found the downloadable file (probably in a loop). The script will run on a headless machine.

An example of the complete link is:

```
http://centos.bio.lmu.de/7/isos/x86_64/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1511.iso
```

The incomplete link is:

```
http://centos.bio.lmu.de/
```

Now the script has to find the latest directory, which is `7/`, go into that directory and find `/isos` and repeat it till it reaches this file `CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1511.iso`.

Since I am new to programming and bash any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The fIrst link is broken, the second link redirects to a (Spanish?) carrier / provider. Please fix this as currently this may look like an attempt to spam the company linked in the second link.

Comment: That was just an dummy example. Now i have added another example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
#! /bin/bash

re='^[0-9.]+$'  #regex to match digits and dots

VERSION_1=$(  # variable for the CentOS version
lynx --dump http://centos.bio.lmu.de/ |grep "/$" | \
while read i
do
  TMP_VERSION=`echo $i |awk -F "/" '{print $(NF-1)}'`
  if [[ $TMP_VERSION =~ $re ]] ; then
     echo $TMP_VERSION
  fi
done | sort -t . |tail -1)

VERSION_2=$(  #Variable for the ISO name
lynx --dump http://centos.bio.lmu.de/$VERSION_1/isos/x86_64/ |grep DVD| grep "\.iso$" |awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'| \
while read i
do
  echo $i
done |tail -1
)

wget http://centos.bio.lmu.de/$VERSION_1/isos/x86_64/$VERSION_2
```